# How can i get the last commit from squashed commit in git

Tags: git, version-control

I want to have the

```
1. Commit hash
2. commit date
3. commit author
4. commit message from last commit
```

My problem is that if i use `git log -1` then it shows all the squashed commits but i only want to have the latest commit from those squeashed commits

Answer (score 1):

A squashed commit is a new commit made of the merging of other commits. Unlike a merge, it doesn't retain any reference to its component commits. You can't get back to any of the original commits through the squashed commit. You may be able to find the original commits in the reflog if they're still hanging around in the object's folder.

Here's an example branch with 4 commits, `A` being the first, `D` being the most recent:

```
A - B - C - D
```

If you rebase to squash `C` into `B`, a new commit `E` is made of those two commits, and it's parent is `A`. `D` is copied to a new commit - `D¹` - with a different committer time, and with a parent of `B` (instead of `C`):

```
A - E - D¹
```

The original `B` and `C` will exist for awhile, but they won't be referenced (unless something else in the commit DAG also referenced them), and eventually they'll expire. This is where they'd be if you could see them:

```
A - E - D¹
 \
  \
    B - C - D  (these are no longer visible)
```